# await конструктор в javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

у меня есть функция которая вызывает несколько раз конструктор типа

```
let k = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < some.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(new WorkPlace(some[i]), 1000 * k);
  k = k + 1;
}
```

мне это не совсем подходит, так как в конструкторе есть много реквест запросов, то невозможно предвидеть когда какой конструктор выполнит свое действие и я бы хотел выполнять каждый some[i] последовательно отправляя в конструктор по мере выполнения предыдущего WorkPlace[i-1]

думаю возможно переписать конструктор типа Class Workplace(data) в обычную функцию function Workplace(data) и вызывать так же через new, но с промисами внутри функции и через async/await дожидаться выполнения каждого, это муторно и не очень мне нравится, может есть какой то другой способ ?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, думая, что вызываете `new WorkPlace(some[i])` с задержкой в `1000 * k` секунд.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Данный вариант будет работать, если `WorkPlace` написан с использованием `promice` или же `async/await`

```
some.forEach(async function(item, i) {
 await new WorkPlace(item);
});
```

Comment: В данном случае, что такое `WorkPlace`? Функция или конструктор?

Comment: конструктор class LBC{
  constructor(offer) {......} .  а я могу колбек передать в конструктор и через библиотеку tress дожидаться пока сработает колбек мой? если да то как )

Comment: async в forEach не будет работать